# spyder error while debugging and not giving input

Tags: python, debugging, compiler-errors, spyder

this question is kinda for acknowledgement of an error that spyder ide has, and also would be nice if you know the solution share it with us.
I ran a code like this :

```
def q(s=""):
    if s==0:
        inp=input("enter something to abrupt")
        if inp!="":
            1/0
    if s==1:
        1/0
while 1:
    q(s=0)
    q(1)#debug pointer was here
```

I didn't enter an input I exited the debugging and I got the error

```
Program interrupted. (Use 'cont' to resume).
--Return--

!exit

[SpyderKernelApp] WARNING | Invalid Message:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\ipykernel\kernelbase.py", line 896, in _input_request
    [self.stdin_socket], [], [self.stdin_socket], 0.01
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\zmq\sugar\poll.py", line 147, in select
    return_sockets = zmq_poll(sockets, timeout)
  File "zmq/backend/cython/_poll.pyx", line 143, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll
  File "zmq/backend/cython/_poll.pyx", line 123, in zmq.backend.cython._poll.zmq_poll
  File "zmq/backend/cython/checkrc.pxd", line 13, in zmq.backend.cython.checkrc._check_rc
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spyderpdb.py", line 216, in sigint_handler
    self.set_trace(sys._getframe())
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 92, in trace_dispatch
    return self.dispatch_return(frame, arg)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\bdb.py", line 154, in dispatch_return
    if self.quitting: raise BdbQuit
bdb.BdbQuit
```

so it got stuck in debugging mode so I had to close the program entirely. not of a huge issue but good to inform the team to fix it, and also if you know the answer pls tell me and everyone to know.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) What is your Spyder version?

Comment: @CarlosCordoba 5.0.0 or 5.0.5 .

Comment: It looks like an installation issue. I recommend you to remove Anaconda and reinstall it again.

Comment: @CarlosCordoba ok i will inform you of result, btw I have suggestion for your slow completion issue, try using higher default time for completion timeout . I changed it from 200ms to 5000 and I have not problem with it anymore, im sure this default will remove many naggings. wish best for your team.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I'll try it to see how it works.